# How do you get user input from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, browser

I use Codecademy workspaces for javascript. As of now, I'm trying to find a way to access user input from Node.js but I can't find any way to do it. I've used all the methods online like

`const readline = require("readline");`

or

`const input = prompt();`

but none of them worked. Is there any way I can get past this?

Keep in mind that I access node.js from Codecademy which is on browser, so I can't install prompt-sync or any of that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there doesn't seem to be a way do that currently. [This](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/cannot-input-in-terminal-on-codeacademy-workspace/630954) is from an earlier discussion on CodeAcademy forum, and it seems that the input limitation still exists.